# How to get the all user installed app list in api level above 33 in android

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, mobile-development

As per new android update
`packagemanager.getinstalledapplication()` method is deprecated so how to fetch the all installed app in my mobile device.

How to get list of installed application?